# How can I run a junit test suite using maven and receive summary output similar to individual tests?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

When running individual junit test classes using maven's surefire plugin, I get output similar to the following where the test results are displayed for each individual test class:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running my.package.MyTestClass1
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.50 sec - in my.package.MyTestClass1
Running my.package.MyTestClass2
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.25 sec - in my.package.MyTestClass2
Running my.package.MyTestClass3
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.74 sec - in my.package.MyTestClass3
...
Results :

Tests run: 133, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

However, if I run the same classes via a test suite class, I get output similar to the following where the test results are aggregated for the entire suite:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running my.package.AllTests
Tests run: 133, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 32.44 sec - in my.package.AllTests

Results :

Tests run: 133, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

How can I run the classes via a test suite class, but yet still see the test result information for each individual test class defined in the suite?

Comment: Take a look at: [Maven Surefire Report Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) and [Maven Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/)

Comment: I read through those pages prior to asking the question.   If a custom runlistener is the only way to do this, then I guess this question turns into more of a junit-centric question.   On the surface, one would think this should be a fairly easy problem to solve without writing custom code, but perhaps not.

Comment: What is the reason to use a Suites instead of leaving the work to do by Maven sure fire plugin?

Comment: The main reason we use suite classes is to allow us to group our test classes in various ways and to ensure that they are run in a predictable order within those groups.   For example, within a given project, we might want a small subset of test classes (smoke test) run during the main part of our automated build, but then run a larger super set during a post-build test run.   In fact, we could conceivably run different groups of tests in parallel on different machines after the main part of the build has finished.

Comment: I think the behavior I'm seeing is a byproduct of the Junit run listener that is part of maven-surefire-plugin.   I configured my own run listener, and it was invoked as expected, but all its output went into <project-dir>/target/surefire-reports/<testclassname>-output.txt rather than to stdout.     Perhaps what I need to do is *replace* the run listener used by surefire, but I don't think there's an easy way to configure that, as the "listener" config property is intended to *add* custom run listeners to surefire, not replace surefire's own run listener.

Comment: Current investigation seems to point away from the surefire plugin's run listener, as it seems not to be responsible for writing the testcase progress information to the console.   I guess the other alternative is that it's the default Junit runner/listener combination that produces the current behavior.